# Make a DataTable that Doesn't Have Constraints But Contains All Data

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable

**WHAT I NEED**

I'm looking to create a DataTable that has all of the same Data, but none of the constraints associated with any table. I will do INNER JOIN's on a bunch of table to coalesce all of the data that I need. It goes as such:

1. There will several **Test** entries. Each one will have a collection of **TestStep**. There will always be a collection of **TestStep**'s within each **Test**. Both tables have ID's that can't be NULL.
2. There may be other pieces of data that will be connected to both **Test**'s as well as **TestStep**'s. Sometimes, **Test**'s will have a collection of **TestParam**'s that will be linked to each **Test**, but not always. **TestParam** has an ID field that can't be NULL.
3. Sometimes there will be a collection of parameters for each **TestStep** as well. Sometimes not. **TestStepParam** has an ID field that can't be NULL.
4. Sometimes there will be a collection of **ScreenShot**'s for each **TestStep**. Again, sometimes not. **ScreenShot** has an ID field that can't be NULL.
   If I execute the SQL where I join all of these tables within the SQLite browser, and say there aren't any **ScreenShot**'s that are connected to a certain **TestStep**, then it will just say *NULL* in that cell **(SQL is typed below)**. If I do the exact same thing using the code below, it throws an exception. How do I make it ignore constraints when I'm using **DataTable.Load(SqLiteDataReader)**?

**WHAT I HAVE**

Below is the method that I have for getting the data from a SQLite database which works perfectly fine:

```
private static List<DataTable> HitDB(params string[] sqls)
    {
        List<DataTable> ldt = new List<DataTable>();

        using (SqliteConnection cnn = new SqliteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            foreach (string sql in sqls)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(sql, cnn);
                SqliteDataReader sqldr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //this is what I would have hoped would have fixed this.
                dt.Constraints.Clear();                    

                try
                {
                    //This is where the error is thrown.
                    dt.Load(sqldr);
                }
                catch (ConstraintException exc)
                {
                    Wr.Err($"CONSTRAINT EXCEPTION CAUGHT: \n{exc}\n\n");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Wr.Err($"EXCEPTION CAUGHT: {exc}\n\n");
                }
                ldt.Add(dt);
            }

            cnn.Close();
        }

        return ldt;
    }
```

for the sql, I have:

```
string sql = $"SELECT * FROM Test t " +
$"INNER JOIN TestStep ts " +
$"ON t.ID = ts.Test_ID " +
$"LEFT OUTER JOIN Test_Param tp " +
$"ON t.ID = tp.Test_ID " +
$"LEFT OUTER JOIN TestStep_Param tsp " +
$"ON ts.ID = tsp.TestStep_ID " +
$"LEFT OUTER JOIN ScreenShot ss " +
$"ON ts.ID = ss.TestStep_ID "
```

This is the result when I type it in the SQLite Browser, as well as exactly what I'd like to recreate in C#: [TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRPSi.png)

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried executing `dt.Constraints.Clear();` before loading in the **SqLiteDataReader** but that changes nothing.

**THE EXCEPTION**

```
CONSTRAINT EXCEPTION CAUGHT:
System.Data.ConstraintException: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
   at System.Data.DataTable.EnableConstraints()
   at System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints(Boolean value)
   at System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.LoadAdapter.FillFromReader(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Load(IDataReader reader, LoadOption loadOption)
   at Automonom.AutoDB.HitDB(String sql) in C:\VS Projects\Automonom\AutoDB.cs:line 555
```

Comment: What exact error is thrown when you run the code? Can you [edit] your question to include it?

Comment: I would just go with NoSQL solution. Constraints is actually one of benefits of SQL, but from my view you can just store documents. This will also provide you with copy-paste or regress control of your tests. And would probably store them in git - for version control, believe me - you WILL need it at some point, this way you can track new features/behaviors in your tests.

Comment: EDIT: I've added exactly what exception it is that I keep on getting

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm storing the RESULTS not the actual test themselves. I'm running selenium scripts and the results of those scripts I'm storing in an SQLite database. I have several fields. I have a Test, which holds several TestSteps, which are basically just smaller incraments of the same thing. It's just a way of holding onto the data and displaying it

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to store tests in database, I suggest you to avoid this because:

1. No support of version control

Imagine your managers ask you to test new feauture. This will involve: refactoring of existing tests, adding new tests, removing expired ones, documenting behavior of tests, linking them with some task tracker link. Do you ready to support all of this cases?

2. Hard to migrate

SQL is way harder to change: it affects existing data tables schema, queries. Are you sure your schema change once a year?

3. Copy-paste problem

Tests is very dynamic structure, it is cheapier to copy-paste test with slight changes here and there, rather than extending database schema.

4. Team development/testing

If you have multiple features, multiple CI/CD pipelines how you can run your new tests not affecting production tests? You ready to situation where developer can potentially break pipeline for everyone and for production?

Just store your tests in files, in GIT as documents.

Comment: 1) This doesn't answer the question. 2) You assume the OP is doing this for a work environment, when it could perfectly fine be a homework project, assignment, etc. 3) You assume the OP wants/can change this approach

Comment: Well, this is professional community and if there is a Test team member - I hope he will see my answer as well as OP. And I really eager to see where database can help to store tests, other than you outsource those tests to 3rd party by providing them schema, a contract to work with. Sharing experience is often better than providing hacks.

Comment: The test table store the RESULTS of the tests that I go through

Comment: I'm running selenium scripts that will store the results in an SQLite database. Each Test has several steps that it needs to complete which is why I set it up that way. It's also a way of displaying the results in a more cohesive manner. Basically, I want to make it so that I can load in a table, built from an SQL query, and then query that table several times thoughout my code. I don't want the constraints because they make this impossible to complete otherwise